# How to set the printer properties programatically?

Tags: windows, scripting, printing

As a paper saving drive throughout the organization, we plan to set 2 page printing (back to back) as default setting on all the Windows machines. Is it possible to program this in .NET / Java (or any scripting language)? Can we change printer properties by a program?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with WMI using VBScript or Powershell.

Here is a blog post with lots of info to get started (including duplexing info):
http://blogs.technet.com/print/archive/2009/10/16/printer-management-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, Do you think this can be done on individual boxes, we currently do not have a print server.Let me explore it, meanwhile, if you had some "Hello world" kinda scripts, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use WMI to access individual boxes. See the example here where you can iterate over a list of machines to perform some work: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_printers.htm#Example_2:__List_Printers_Found_in_an_Array_of_Computers